# How to open txt file from openrowset Function in Synapse analytics

Tags: t-sql, azure-sql-database, azure-data-lake

I am writing this SQL query to fetch data from Delimitedtext file. But getting an error
**Invalid or unknown format type 'txt'.**

```
select * from OPENROWSET
    (
        bulk 'https://demoaccname.dfs.core.windows.net/demoadlscontainer/simplenotebook.txt',
        format= 'txt'
    
    )as result
```

Comment: The error is telling you the problem. There is only *one* value recognised for [`FORMAT =`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#format); `'CSV'`.

Comment: This mean we can access data from only csv file?

Comment: No, that's not what it means; it just means that if you are using the `FORMAT =` syntax, then it does need to a CSV (like) file that is *"compliant to the [RFC 4180](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) standard."*.

Comment: Okay so how can i access .txt filr can you help me on that

Comment: I have no idea what that txt file looks like, so I can't comment. I assume you could just drop the `format` part, and then process the transformation using T-SQL. Or perhaps you need to define a format file. We don't know, we can't see your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can access the data of .txt file in synapse dedicated pool using below process.
click on the linked in data and open the storage account and right click on the table will get bulk load option.
Image for reference:

[image]

we will get below page

[image]

[image]

Fill the required fields then code will generate automatically in sql. when we click on sql script.
we will get code as mentioned below:

[image]

retrieve the data of the table I got the below result.

[image]

In this way we can access the data of .txt file in synapse dedicated file.

Comment: This technique is good. First we are loading data into SQL Pool from text file. Then we can fetching data from SQL pool